# Virtual listview not showing any text

Tags: listview, winapi, rust

I am trying to create a virtual listview in Rust using the winapi. I got an normal listview working, but the virtual one won't show any data. 
I set the number of items with:

```
user32::SendMessageW(list_hwnd, winapi::LVM_SETITEMCOUNT, (ALL_DATA.read().unwrap().len()-1) as u64, 0);
```

I create the list itself with:

```
let style = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP |
            LVS_NOSORTHEADER | LVS_OWNERDATA | LVS_AUTOARRANGE |
            LVS_SINGLESEL | LVS_REPORT;
let hwnd = user32::CreateWindowExW(
    0,
    wc.as_ptr() as *mut _,
    to_wstring("").as_ptr() as *mut _,
    style,
    0,
    0,
    rc_client.right - rc_client.left,
    rc_client.bottom - rc_client.top,
    hwnd_parent,
    0 as HMENU,
    // IDC_MAIN_LISTVIEW,
    h_instance,
    std::ptr::null_mut()
);
```

In the `LVN_GETDISPINFOW` message I try to add text with:

```
if (mask & LVIF_TEXT) == 0 {
    let len = ALL_DATA.read().unwrap().len();
    if ix >= len - 1 {
        println!("ix bigger then index! ix: {:?} len: {:?}", ix, len);
        return 0;

    }
    let ref item = ALL_DATA.read().unwrap()[ix];

    let f = |key| {
        let ref vec = STRING_CACHE.read().unwrap()[(key)];
        let ptr = STRING_CACHE.read().unwrap()[(key)].as_ptr();
        (ptr, vec.len())
    };

    let (ptr, _) = match (*(l_param as *const NMLVDISPINFOW)).item.iSubItem {
        0 => f(&item.item),
        1 => f(&item.sub_item),
        n => {
            println!("Found subitem: {:?}", n);
            return 0;
        }
    };

    // Try to set text in dispinfo
    (*(l_param as *mut NMLVDISPINFOW)).item.pszText = ptr as LPWSTR;

    return 0;
}
```

`STRING_CACHE` is an `HashMap<String, Vec<u16>>`. I use this so the string is not dropped when returning from `window_prow()`.

When I compile and run the code, it seems to populate the listview but no text is visible.

The [complete code can be found at GitHub](https://github.com/JesperAxelsson/rust-virtual-listview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (mask & LVIF_TEXT) == 0
```

This statement is checking if the `LVIF_TEXT` flag *IS NOT* present.  You need to provide text when the flag *IS* present instead:

```
if (mask & LVIF_TEXT) != 0
```

Or:

```
if (mask & LVIF_TEXT) == LVIF_TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a virtual list view control, so you don't use `LVM_INSERTITEM`; instead, you just call `LVM_SETITEMCOUNT` to set the item count and then the list view will take care of the rest. In particular, you should not be making `LVITEM`s manually, and especially not be using `LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK`.

More references:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh270411(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050615-30/?p=35313

Also, the messages that end with `A` are for backwards compatibility and are not Unicode-aware; if you handle the `W` messages you don't need to handle them.

Comment: I have actually tried this before, sorry for saying that. I have updated the code for SETITEMCOUNT. I use widestrings and make sure the pointer survive and it seems to be set on the item but still no text visible. Does the pointer have to live in a globalalloc or somesuch?

Comment: If you check [the documentation for the `LVITEM` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll see in the `pszText` field documentation that the pointer must remain valid "until after the next notification has been received". I do not know if this means after the next `LVN_GETDISPINFO` for any cell or for the specific cell in question, but it does mean it has to survive after you return from your window procedure. I would not know how to do this in Rust; sorry.

Comment: Thanks any way. I have store all string in a global variable and they are valid as long as the program is running. I have even tried allocating them with GlobalAlloc, but still no text in the ListView.